# CSS images placement in table with absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to cycle through two sets of images using some `Javascript`. In order for each image to replace the old one as it cycles, I need to use `css` and set the `position` to `absolute`.

I'd like to align the image sets in a `html` `table`. If I don't specify positions within the `css`, the two image sets are on top of each other. If I do, they ignore the table, which I think is caused by the `absolute positioning`.

Rather than display a lot of code here, I will share a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n342aadc/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
td {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}

.container img.
.container1 img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/uhvj3734/)

I think you need to specify a width for `td` otherwise it seems to collapse.